# How to allow user view/upload resulting file of select file dialog in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, browser

I have Angular application where users upload files to the server.
Files are received in the following way (not related code removed):

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-select-file-button",
  template: `
     <input type="file" (change)="handleInputChange($event)">
  `
})
export class SelectFileButtonComponent {
  @Output() file: EventEmitter<File> = new EventEmitter<File>();

  handleInputChange(e: any) {
    this.file.emit(e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

So it's an ordinary file selection.
After that, I have a possibility to show the user what file he has selected, what is the size of the file etc.

However, I have the next use case. Users can erroneously select the wrong file and even seeing the name of the file and size still don't understand it. So I need to have a possibility to show the user content of the file.

**What I really would like to avoid is implementing scenario when user uploads the wrong file to the server then sees the link to the uploaded file, downloads it, checks, understands the error and then uploads the correct file again.**

Files can be different - pdf, doc, archives, large size mp3 files.
I've implemented showing file in a new iframe:

```
const reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = (e: any) => {
  this.base64Url = e.target.result;

  const win = window.open();
  win.document.write('<iframe src="' + this.base64Url + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen download></iframe>');
};

reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

There are two problems with the approach:

- firstly, the approach doesn't work with mp3 files on Chrome since it tries to play audio and nothing happens (other files are either shown or instantly downloaded which is fine)
- secondly, as I understand using fileReader the file is stored in RAM. mp3 files can be really large (about hundreds of MB) and they are usually uploaded from mobile phones which memory can be limited.

Can a better approach be used? If not, how to force the browser to start downloading mp3 files instead of opening them? Is it possible to set the correct name for the file in a frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the solution is much more simple than expected.
The main thing is that I already have a file blob so no conversion to base64url required.
Also, browsers block URLs opened from the code by default, so angular sanitizer is needed:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Injecting sanitizer in the component:

```
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
```

Selecting file html:

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleInputChange($event)">
```

Getting file blob code:

```
handleInputChange(e: any) {
    this.file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
  }
```

Url created and sanitized:

```
const w: any = window;
this.url = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl((w.webkitURL || w.URL).createObjectURL(this.file));
```

Using "download" parameter in URL (so the browser doesn't try to open the file and just downloads it with the correct name):

```
<a [href]="url" [download]="file.name">{{file.name}}</a>
```